# Ergo, ex nihilo aliquid et ex nihilo nihil fit

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, history, philosophy-terms, logic

I want to say, "Ergo, something comes from nothing and nothing comes from nothing." Is it correct to translate this as: "Ergo, ex nihilo aliquid et ex nihilo nihil fit"? I'm aware that "ex nihilo aliquid" means "something out of nothing" and that "ex nihilo nihil fit" means "nothing out of nothing".

Comment: What specifically are you unsure about? It seems to me like you answer your own question--the only missing piece was "et" = "and"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is correct and proper.

Comment: Gaudeo et congratulor, quod decem milia punctorum tulisti!

Answer (score 2):

Your translation is fine, but a Roman may have preferred to express the shared prepositional phrase only once, perhaps like this:

Ex nihilo igitur fiunt et aliquid et nihil.

Comment: +1, though I wonder if the singular verb *fit* might be used here instead (not that I have any evidence that it would, just a hunch).

Comment: @TKR certainly a possibility. At that point it's a matter of emphasis, not grammar.